# Can a big-O of a function be larger than the function itself?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

**Assume two (positive) nondecreasing functions f and g such that f(n)=O(g(n)). 
Is 2^f(n)=O(2^g(n)) ?**

In the solution 2 cases are given:

1. Assume f(n) = g(n) = n, in this case they are equal which I totally get it.
2. For the second case the author has assumed that let f(n) = 10n and g(n) = n, **Is this assumption even correct? how can the big-O of a function be larger than the function itself?**

I am missing a keypoint over here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that `10n=O(n)` by definition. If this is not clear to you, go and re-read the definition of the `big-O` notation.

However, `2^(10n)` is not `O(2^n)` because this would imply

```
2^(10n) <= C2^n
```

for some constant `C` and all values of `n` above some threshold `N`.

To see why this is not true, pick some constant `D` such that `C <= 2^D` (for example, `D = lgC`). We get

```
2^(10n) <= C2^n <= (2^D)(2^n) = 2^(D+n)
```

which implies

```
10n <= D + n
```

or

```
9n <= D
```

for all values of `n` above the threshold `N`. But this is impossible because `D` is constant and `9n` is unbounded.

In conclusion, we have a counterexample for the assertion `2^f(n) = O(2^g(n))` and therefore it doesn't generally hold.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I totally get the part where we say that if g(n) = 10n, then O(g(n)) = n,. And also the part where if g(n) = 2^10n , then O(n) != 2^n.

But the problem above is a multiple choice question. and the correct answers were
1)  when f(n) <= g(n). which I get it because it is the very definition of big-O.
2) next answer is sometimes and the explanation by the author is is that in the case when f(n) = 10n and g(n) = n they are not equal. My question is that how can he assume that f(n) = 10n and g(n) = n; when f(n) is the big-O of g(n)??

Comment: If `f(n)=10n` and `g(n)=n`, then `f(n)=O(g(n))` by definition: There exists a constant `C`, namely `10`, such that `f(n)<=Cg(n)` for all `n>=1` (in particular the threshold for `n` is `1`).

Comment: Ohk, so the 'c' in this case was 1/10 I get it now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @pi2018 No, the `C` in this case is `10` because `f(n)=10n <= Cn = Cg(n)` for `C=10`.